# Attaching GDB target remote by command-line

Tags: linux, gdb, gdbserver

How can I specify to GDB that I would like it to connect to a gdbserver, but by command-line, so I don't need to type `target remote` every time.  Is there a way to connect automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> so I don't need to type target remote every time.

This should do:

```
gdb -ex 'target remote ...' ./a.out
```